# Topology; difference between open subsets of $X$ containing $x$ and open neightborhood od $x$?

Tags: notation, terminology

I see my lecture notes and some texts alternate between the two.
What is the difference in saying that "an open subset of $X$ containing $x \in X$" and an "open neighborhood of $x \in X$"?

Comment: No, there is no difference. There would be a difference if the neighborhood was not open

Comment: I go along with @Tryss but caution: there are authors (e.g. Munkres) who define a neighborhood of $x$ as an open set containing $x$.

Comment: Hi, yes I am aware; my notes also says neighborhoods of $x$ is a subset of $X$ that contain an open neighborhood of $x$. But when we say *open* neighborhood of $x$, this is equivalent to an open subset of $X$ containing $x$ then.